# searching fields using grepl in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `grepl` to flag some data that might be interesting in a genetics dataset I have.

An example of the data looks like this

```
test <- c("AAT,TAA,TGA,A,G", "A,AAT,AAAT,AATAAT", "CA,CAA,CAAA")
pattern <- c("TAA", "G", "CAA")
df <- data.frame(test, pattern)
```

What I am trying to do is to create a third column, say `result` that evaluates whether the value in the `pattern` column is in the `test` column.

I tried this:

```
df.result <- df %>% mutate(result = grepl(pattern, test))
```

But for some reason I get a `TRUE, TRUE, FALSE` in the `result` column, which isn't what I'm expecting - I would expect a `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE` result.

I've played around with things like adding a comma to the end of each field, but that didn't seem to work either.

Would appreciate any help with this!

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stringi` package provides string matching functions that are vectorised over both string and pattern;

```
library(stringi)
df %>% mutate(result = stri_detect_regex(test,  pattern))
```

is one answer to the original question. An answer to the question about avoiding substring matches is

```
df %>% mutate(result = stri_detect_regex(test, stri_join('(^|,)', pattern, '(,|$)')))
```

Comment: That is damn brilliant. Thank you so much for introducing me to that package.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `apply()` function:

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, FUN=function(x) grepl(x[2], x[1])

df
#                test pattern result
# 1   AAT,TAA,TGA,A,G     TAA   TRUE
# 2 A,AAT,AAAT,AATAAT       G  FALSE
# 3       CA,CAA,CAAA     CAA   TRUE
```

The `apply` function loops through each row of the df separately, feeding `grepl` with per row information. `grepl` cannot process a vector with three elements in the pattern argument. The help page says:

> If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied [as pattern], the first element is used with a warning.

Thus, the original command `grepl(df$pattern, df$test)` compared the first element from `pattern` (TAA) to the whole vector in `test`.

Comment: I added a column to df with the above code. To store the result in a separate variable, use `df.result <- apply(df, 1, FUN=function(x) grepl(x[2], x[1]))`

Answer (score 3):

This can be otherwise done with `mapply`

```
df$result <- mapply(grepl, df$pattern, df$test)
df$result
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with mapply. I'm still having an issue here, not so much with getting the code to run but with the exact matching. Let me give you an example: If I have a field that has the following text in it "T,AATTT" and I'm trying to use grepl with the pattern "AATTT" I get, a 1, which is what I want. But if I use the pattern "ATTT" I also get a 1. This is not what I want :-( I'm trying to get it to match any of the patterns *exactly* between the commas. I tried the "fixed = TRUE" flag but that didn't seem to work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Steven Perhaps you need a word boundary.  i.e. `grepl("\\bATTT",  "T,AATTT")
#[1] FALSE;
 grepl("\\bAATTT",  "T,AATTT")` .  Using the current code, it can be done with `paste` i.e. `mapply(grepl, paste0("\\", df$pattern, df$test)
#[1] TRUE`